# Separate adjacent values in a column to split them [Python - Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

in my dataframe i have a column [date_time/full_company_name] that contains a date, time and a company name. I want to split the column in order to have 2 columns, one with date and time and one with the company name - the issue is, that they are directly adjacent e.g.

```
[2011-11-19 12:22:10Anderson-Henderson]
```

So my initial idea of using the following code:

```
split = df[['date_time', 'full_company_name']] = df['date_time/full_company_name'].str.split('/', n=1, expand=True)
```

returned 2 columns but one with all the information and the second one without values.
How can I insert a '/' between date and company name in my initial dataframe to make use of this kind of splitting? or is there an easier way overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this by string slicing:

so firstly use `astype()` method and `strip()` method:

```
df['date_time/full_company_name']=df['date_time/full_company_name'].astype(str).str.strip('[]')
```

Finally assign columns:

```
df['date_time']=df['date_time/full_company_name'].str[1:20]
df['full_company_name']=df['date_time/full_company_name'].str[20:-1]
```

Now if you print `df` you will get:

```
    date_time/full_company_name                date_time            full_company_name
0   '2011-11-19 12:22:10Anderson-Henderson'   2011-11-19 12:22:10   Anderson-Henderson
1   '2011-11-19 12:22:10Anderson-Henderson'   2011-11-19 12:22:10   Anderson-Henderson
```

Comment: This works perfectly for most parts, but what if there are missing values in the date_time/full_company_name  column, because it then puts the company name into this column - do you think there is any way around this?

Comment: It puts 'company_name' into 'date_time' column?

Comment: Yes, but only if the date_time column is empty

Comment: then  pass `errors` parameter in`to_datetime()` method...i.e `df['date_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'],errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 1):

I hope you find a better solution but until you do, I've come up with one that works.

Split by ":" into multiple columns, then take the seconds from the name column and shift that to the date column.

```
df[['date', 'hour', 'name']] = df["col"].str.split(':', expand=True)
df['date'] = df['date'] + ":" + df['hour'] + ":" + df['name'].str[:2]
df['name'] = df['name'].str[2:]
```

Output:

```
col                                     date                 name
2011-11-19 12:22:10Anderson-Henderson   2011-11-19 12:22:10 Anderson-Henderson
```